# Overload Equality Operator (==) to compare String and Int

Tags: swift, protocols, equality

I am experiencing with protocols and challenged myself to write a code snippet that overloads the `==` operator so that it `returns true` when I compare a random `String` with value `"42"` with a `Int` of value `42`. Please don't question the usefulness by simply returning `42` on a `String`, the main point is getting the `Equality Operator` to run on the two different types.

Here is what I tried:

#### Version 1

```
import Foundation

protocol IntTransformable: Equatable {
    func toInt() -> Int
}

extension String: IntTransformable {
    func toInt() -> Int {
        return 42
    }
}

extension Int: IntTransformable {
    func toInt() -> Int {
        return self
    }
}

extension IntTransformable {
    static func == (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool {
        return lhs.toInt() == rhs.toInt()
    }
}

// throws: Ambiguous reference to operator function '=='
if "42" == 42 {
    print("equal")
} else {
    print("unequal")
}
```

#### Version 2

```
import Foundation

protocol IntTransformable: Equatable {
    func toInt() -> Int
}

extension String: IntTransformable {
    func toInt() -> Int {
        return 42
    }
}

extension Int: IntTransformable {
    func toInt() -> Int {
        return self
    }
}

extension IntTransformable {
    // throws: Protocol 'IntTransformable' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements
    static func == (lhs: IntTransformable, rhs: IntTransformable) -> Bool {
        return lhs.toInt() == rhs.toInt()
    }
}

// throws: Ambiguous reference to operator function '=='
if "42" == 42 {
    print("equal")
} else {
    print("unequal")
}
```

Comment: You can get your protocol working as simply as `static func == (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool {
        return lhs.toInt() == rhs.toInt()
    }` However, using the operator on a `String` and `Int` will still result in the same error.

Comment: You can't do this using a protocol because of the ways in which a protocol is not really a type.

Comment: @DávidPásztor thanks for the code improvement hint.

Comment: @matt if I cannot use a protocol, what could I do instead?

Comment: You would just write the operator plain and simple.

Comment: BTW, if you want to introduce different ideas of equality for a type `T`, I would recommend you make a `struct` that wraps a `T`, and conforms to equatable by implementing the new definition of equality. Defining `==` over existing types usually leads to this sort of ambiguity/mess

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea trying to make Swift work like Javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use these two functions:

```
func ==(lhs: String, rhs: @autoclosure ()->Int) -> Bool {
    guard let stringIntValue = Int(lhs) else { return false }
    return stringIntValue == rhs()
}

func ==(lhs: Int, rhs: String) -> Bool {
    guard let stringIntValue = Int(rhs) else { return false }
    return lhs == stringIntValue
}
```

But if you really want to involve `Protocol`s here, you should do this like:

```
extension IntTransformable {
    static func ==<T: IntTransformable>(lhs: Self, rhs: T) -> Bool {
        return lhs.toInt() == rhs.toInt()
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
print( 42 == "42" )
print( "42" == 42 )
```

Comment: In your second example I guess you meant `return lhs.toInt() == rhs.toInt()`

Comment: i think the purpose of the protocol is to have multipole cases of comparisons. Like, Double, Float, Int32, Char etc. Having the first solution in this case would be a lot of different functions

Comment: @Vollan `toInt()` limited it to `Int`, Then he should consider using overloads of the function, instead of using this strict protocol.

Comment: The protocol version does not work for me and why are you using an `autoclosure` in the tow functions?

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini I was thinking more like `char to int` `double to int` `float to int` etc etc. not generic as in comparing `"foo" == 35.0123`

Comment: @Vollan Using `==` for Equality with floating point types is fundamentally broken (for almost all use cases), so that's a complete non-starter.

Comment: `autoclosure` wraps the second argument in a closure, so it wont execute if the first argument is not convertible to `Int`. Epic performance booster in some situations. Inspired from the [Swift Source Code](https://github.com/apple/swift) @ChrisGraf

Comment: @ChrisGraf I updated the protocol version. So it should work for you too now.

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini doesn't the `guard let` statement pretend any following code from executing in case `lhs` is not convertible with `Int()`? Where exactly does the performance boost come from? I tried finding an explanation/example in the `swift code` but couldn't finde one. Would appreciate any further reference/explanations. My only explanation is that passing a `Int` directly does cost performance whereas an `autoclosure` only costs performance when executed.

Comment: Not if the **argument itself** is a function! Search for autoclosure to find articles [like this](https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/https-medium-com-pavelgnatyuk-autoclosure-what-why-and-when-swift-641dba585ece)

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini got it, thanks mate! I just read through another article about it and it got clearer. I missed the point that the argument itself could be passed as a function/method/. Thanks for your help. Learned a lot here.

Answer (score 1):

You're way overthinking this. There is no reason to use protocols here, and you really can't do it because protocols are not really types. Just write your operator(s) at top level:

```
func == (lhs: Int, rhs: String) -> Bool {
    return lhs == Int(rhs)
}
func == (lhs: String, rhs: Int) -> Bool {
    return Int(lhs) == rhs
}
```

Testing:

```
print(5 == "5") // true
```

Comment: I was also trying to get around defining the operator on a global level, but I guess you are right when you say I am overthinking this.

Comment: @ChrisGraf You can declare them as an extension to Int as well if that makes any difference

Comment: Operators aren't namespaced. `==` is `==`, whether defined in a struct or in at the top level. It doesn't really make any difference

Comment: @Alexander The thing I was trying to get away from is the Self / IntTransformable cuteness in the OP's code. Plain and simple is often best. "Say what you mean" is a programming koan.

Comment: @matt My comment was in response to Chris' "trying to get around defining the operator on a global level"

Comment: @Alexander There is an at-sign operator for addressing your comment to Chris. :)

Comment: @matt I'm aware. I thought I used it, but I must have forgotten

Answer (score -3):

create a string extension, like

public string ToInt(this int value)
{
// some conversion code

return ConvertedStringValue;
}

or you can use a uint.TryParse(string value, out uint output)
this statement will return true if conversion is successful.